# MercadoPago - Pago con monto variable

Tags: mercadopago

Buenas A todos, estoy iniciandome con MercadoPAgo. Bajé el SDK, hace más de una semana que trato de hacer pruebas y no logro que funcione nada. Les pido si me pueden dar algo de código básico o que me indiquen luego de instalar el SDK si hay algo más que configurar. Estoy trabajando con PHP 7, xampp para windows.

Necesito posibilitar que una mutual pueda cobrar monto variables para un sólo concepto, ofreciendo los distintos tipos de pago. Y que una vez terminada la transacción posea un comprobante. Y en caso de que el pago no se acredite instantaneamente no sé como validar el pago posteriormente.

Actualmente ejecuté lo que muestra como ejemplo la página...

```
"
<?php
require_once ('mercadopago.php');

$mp = new MP('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');

$mp->sandbox_mode(TRUE);

$preference_data = array(
"items" => array(
    array(
        "title" => "Multicolor kite",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "currency_id" => "ARS", // Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
        "unit_price" => 10.00
    )
)
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pay</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['sandbox_init_point']; ?>">Pay</a>
</body>
</html>"
```

Y me arroja el siguiente resultado:

> Warning: require_once(mercadopago.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagosprueba\index.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'mercadopago.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pagosprueba\index.php on line 2

Gracias a todos por adelantado.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo te falta incluir el archivo mercadopago.php o al menos no esta en la ubicación. Según ese codigo el archivo de mercadopago tiene que estar al lado del index.php dentro de la carpeta pagosprueba.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!!! Me faltaba el archivo que ya bajé desde https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-php.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, recuerda revisar [answer] para realizar preguntas en el sitio.